# Best way to implement a Load balancing Server

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, load-balancing

I already have a java socket server for a speech application.

My problem is that sometimes I have some native erros that kills my server. It's not easy to investigate theses erros, there are many clients and threads accessing my server.

I'm thinking to implement a Load Balancing Server, to redirect any request to all active server, and restart dead servers.

How can I do this in Java? I need to open the I/O Streams and R/W to make the connection manually? Or there is a easy way to redirect a java socket connection?

Comment: Sorry, with 723 points I think you can read. I wrote that I already have a huge server running. I CANNOT choose a open solution and reimplement all my server. I know the scope of SO question, and I already have made many question as that!

Comment: @mttdbrd, It's a java server. I cannot just fork, or can I? All I can do is read and write on sockets, but I think if I build a server to read and redirect the socket will be too slow. I'm justing asking if I can redirect the output to another proccess without read and write. I have many native code that close my server on an internal error. If I'm not clear in my question about all my pitfalls, please be clear to me.